# Area of triangle with given coordinates of the vertices

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

The question for my math is:

> "Sharon made a scale drawing of a triangular park. The coordinate for the vertices of the park are: $(-10,5)$, $(15,5)$, $(10,12)$. What is the area of the triangular park in square meters?

(I used the formula: $\frac{1}{2}\left( x_1(y_2-y_3)+ x_2(y_3-y_1)+ x_3(y_1-y_2)\right)$ The answer is got is: $92.5$. But the answer is $87.5$ (according to the online practice test).

Comment: why do you have 

Comment: Instead of using the formula, just plot the coordinates on the $xy$-plane and draw the corresponding triangle. Then use the formula provided by @Bernard. As a plotting aid you can use https://www.easycalculation.com/analytical/draw-triangle.php

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use this formula: the basic 1/2 height × base will do, as you very simply get a base and a height for this triangle.

Answer (score 2):

Using determinant method:

$$\text{Area}=\frac{1}{2}
|\det \left[ \begin{array}{} 1&1&1\\-10&15&10\\ 5&5&12\end{array}\right]|$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}
|\det \left[ \begin{array}{} 1&0&0\\-10&25&20\\ 5&0&7\end{array}\right]|$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\times25\times7=87.5$$

Comment: See:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula

Comment: This too:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Computing_the_area_of_a_triangle

Answer (score 1):

When I put the formula in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2%20*%20%28-10*%285-12%29%20%2B%2015*%2812-5%29%20%2B%2010*%285-5%29%29), I get $87.5$, so you probably just put in some of the values incorrectly.  However, as Bernard points out, the complicated formula you have is overkill for this problem: the points are actually nice enough the the usual $\frac{1}{2}\times\text{base}\times\text{height}$ formula is simple to apply.

Here's a picture of the situation:
[image]

The points $(-10,5)$ and $(15,5)$ both lie on the line $y= 5$ (since they have the same $y$ coordinate).  So, if you take the line segment between the two points to be the base, the height will be given by the distance between the line $y=5$ and the point $(10,12)$.  Can you find that distance?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

base = $ \sqrt{(15+10)^2+(5-5)^2} = 25$

This case:

$y_2 - y_1 = \text{height}$

$ 12 - 5 = 7$ is height

area = $\frac{25 * 7}{2} = 87.5$

Answer (score 0):

The actual determinant method is as follows:-

$\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{vmatrix}
 x_{1} & y_{1} & 1 \\ 
 x_{2} & y_{2} &1 \\
x_{3} & y_{3} & 1
\end{vmatrix}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left|x_1(y_2-y_3)-y_1(x_2-x_3)+1(x_2-x_3)\right|$

Comment: \\ The points in your formula must be set down in anticlockwise order; if not, the result will be the negative of the actual area.

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi What does | | stands for? Modulus of a number gives us the absolute value regardless of the sign.